# New class that inherits a class that is output of a function

Tags: python, python-pptx

I've been using the `python-pptx` library recently and have been asked to make it "easy" to build some simple functions to create a powerpoint slide deck. The `python-pptx` library has a powerful (and handy) API but I've further simplified things for my company's use case by making wrappers for adding a 1. title slide, 2. slide with an image, 3. slide with a table, and a 4. slide with bulleted content. In a recent code review, a coworker suggested that I create a class that inherits from `python-pptx` and has these four functions as methods rather than have each fx return nothing and simply add a slide to an extant presentation or one that was instantiated by `pptx.Presentation()`.

I can do that pretty easily as

```
from pptx import Presentation

class CAPresentation:
    def __init__(self, file_name: Optional[str] = None) -> None:
        self.presentation: pptx.presentation.Presentation = Presentation(pptx=file_name)

    [methods go here]
```

but this forces me to use `self.presentation` to access the `pptx.presentation.Presentation` object [that is returned from the `pptx.Presentation()` function](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/presentation.html). I think this is fine, to be honest, but coworker (and more-experience python coder) would like me to try and figure out a way to subclass `Presentation` entirely, so that I don't have to act on `self.presentation`, but just `self` instead.

`pptx.Presentation()` is a function, not a class but returns [a `pptx.presentation.Presentation` object](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/pptx/presentation.html#Presentation) that I can't seem to work with. If I try using

```
from pptx.presentation import Presentation as PresentationClass

class CAPresentation(PresentationClass):

[methods here]
```

this fails because `PresentationClass` requires additional arguments that I cannot provide.

[image]

In fact, the docs say that `pptx.presentation.Presentation` object is "not intended to be constructed directly" so it seems to me that what I'm trying to do goes against the author's wishes.

Can I do what I'm trying to do? If yes, how?

Comment: It looks like `pptx.Presentation` is a function that builds the object that you need. You probably want to look into that function's code to check how a presentation object is built. Then you'll need to subclass a presentation object AND redefine the `pptx.Presentation` function

Comment: I see you have shown: `class CAPresentation(PresentationClass):`. Please update your question with the `__init__()` method for that class.

Comment: @quamrana There was no `__init__()` for that class. My understanding is that if I want to inherit from the `PresentationClass` object, I shouldn't redefine `__init__()`.

Comment: Where did you get that understanding from? Did you look at the source code for this library? That's what I've been doing. I think you need an `__init__()`.

Comment: @quamrana Perhaps it's an outdated--or incorrect--understanding. Although I'm not a python expert, I have been trying to understand the source code for the library, yes.

Comment: I think you need an `__init__()` that calls `super()`, not for `Presentation`, but for its super class.